# Задать URL параметры из .txt или из другой html страницы

Tags: html, url

Добрый день. Имеется следующий кусок `html` кода:

```
<form method="get" target="_blank" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/?" >
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="99946839-e98f-4bea-9c00-d3f3ae0dec7b" />
<input type="submit" value="Start The Game" />
```

То есть как только пользователь кликает на кнопку `start the game`, он переходит на новую страницу `http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=test&token=99946839-e98f-4bea-9c00-d3f3ae0dec7b`

Также в наличии есть `tokens.txt` со списком валидных токенов.
Каким образом я могу сделать так, чтобы при каждом клике на `start the game` генерировалась новая ссылка с различными токенами из моего `tokens.txt` при условии, что каждый токен указан в новой строке?

Иными словами, при каждом переходе по кнопке, параметр `token` должен меняться:
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=test&token=99946839-e98f-4bea-9c00-d3f3ae0dec7b`
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=test&token=02133b25-39ab-4b48-b933-f448e6d0e409`
и так далее.

Еще один вариант: я могу хранить список токенов на другой `html` странице и экспортировать их оттуда как `value` для параметра `token`, как в этом случае можно осуществить экспорт?

Comment: Ну так вы изначально форму сгенерируйте с различными токенами

Comment: @RazGalstyan я новенький в этом деле, можете подсказать как оно должно выглядеть? или навести на примеры, литературу...

Comment: Вы в `php` вообще рабираетесь? У вас форма генерируется в `php`?

Comment: работаю в `html`, сгенерировать хотел бы в `javascript`

Comment: Все ровно что бы достать контент файла вам нужен `php`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fread.php,  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rand.php

Comment: @RazGalstyan спасибо за ссылки и информацию, но у меня немного другая ситуация: я должен использовать `xml` файл, в котором я не могу просто так взять и включить `php` части (для этого требуется работать в `.php` расширении), может, есть вариант использования `javascript` в моем `xml`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72121/discussion-between-raz-galstyan-and-nikolai).